# Regex to find 1st part of string in 2nd part?

Tags: regex, calibre

I'm trying to write a regex for use in Calibre (python) to find ebooks that have the series name in brackets in the title. I have a custom column with the series name and title separated by a "~", for example:

```
"The Series~The Book Title (The Series)"
```

Best I can come up with finds anything with at least one letter from the series name in brackets in the title:

```
(.+)~.*[\(\1\)].*
```

I only want to find those that have the whole of the first part of the string in brackets at the end of the second part, it can contain extra info.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the square brackets and teplace the last .* with $.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Notepad++:

```
(.+)~[^\(]*\(\1\).*
```

I'm not sure it will work the same in python, but regexp processors are usually very similar, so try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is pretty close, you can change a little your regex and have this:

```
(.+?)~.*[([]\1[)\]].*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN9mO6/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will match strings like:

```
The Series~The Book Title (The Series)
The Series~The Book Title [The Series]
```

However, if you just want to match words with paretheses, then you can have:

```
(.+?)~.*[(]\1[)].*
or
(.+?)~.*\(\1\).*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN9mO6/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. They work perfectly in the python demo but for some unknown reason don't work in Calibre. Seems like one character is the most it will match from the capture group. Must be a limitation in the regex system Calibre uses.